# Statement closed exception when getting ManyToMany related elements

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have two entities with a relation ManyToMany between them. For some reason, when I try to get all the entities from the database I get a `"statement closed"` exception.

Here is some code :

```
public class Famille {

    [...]

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "famille_personne", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="famille_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personne_id"))
    private Set<Personne> listPersonne;

    [...]

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object){

        if(object instanceof Famille){
            Famille famille = (Famille) object;

            return (nom.equals(famille.getNom()) 
                    && ((listPersonne == null && famille.getListPersonne() == null)
                        || (listPersonne != null && new HashSet(listPersonne).equals(new HashSet(famille.getListPersonne())))
                        )
                    );
        }
        return false;

    }
}

public class Personne {

    [...]

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "famille_personne", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personne_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="famille_id"))
    private Set<Famille> listFamille;

    [...]

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object){

        if(object instanceof Personne){
            Personne personne = (Personne) object;

            return (matricule.equals(personne.getMatricule()) && nom.equals(personne.getNom()));
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(matricule, nom);
    }
}
```

And here is the method with the two queries I can't execute in the same time :

```
public ArrayList<Famille> getListFamille(){

    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


    ArrayList<Famille> listFamille = new ArrayList<Famille>();
    listFamille.addAll(entityManager.createQuery("from Famille", Famille.class).getResultList());

    entityManager.close();

    return listFamille;
}

public ArrayList<Personne> getListPersonne(){

    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


    ArrayList<Personne> listPersonne = new ArrayList<Personne>();
    listPersonne.addAll(entityManager.createQuery("from Personne", Personne.class).getResultList());

    entityManager.close();

    return listPersonne;
}
```

Here is the exception I got :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
```

Can someone explain me how it work and why i get this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending whether you are using the container to manage your transactions or you must manage them manually, then:

**Container Manager**

You do not need to close the entityManager manually, just let the container do it for you:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public ArrayList<Famille> getListFamille(){

    ArrayList<Famille> listFamille = new ArrayList<Famille>();
    listFamille.addAll(entityManager.createQuery("from Famille", Famille.class).getResultList());

    // entityManager.close();

    return listFamille;
}
```

**Manual management**

You would have to create and close the transaction addtionally to what you have written:

```
public ArrayList<Famille> getListFamille(){

        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        ArrayList<Famille> listFamille = new ArrayList<Famille>();
        listFamille.addAll(entityManager.createQuery("from Famille", Famille.class).getResultList());

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();

        return listFamille;
    }
```

**Update**

The error does not show it but your mappings are a bit odd.

You seem to eagerly fetch both sides of the mapping and that may lead to some cyclic reference problems.

I would suggest removing the EAGER fetching from one side of the relationship i.e.:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "famille_personne", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personne_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="famille_id"))
private Set<Famille> listFamille;
```

Comment: I have transformed my two method as you said and it still don't work. Why should i begin/commit a transaction ? Never done it this way before when i was getting some values and it always worked

Comment: i think it might be the problem with the eager fetching on both sides.. please check my updated answer

Comment: Sorry for long time for response. I've tried as you said and i get a "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" exception. Sometimes i want to get Personne.listFamille and sometimes Famille.listPersonne so it can't work ...

Comment: That happens because you are trying to access the collection outside of a transaction. Btw.. in your hashCode / equals methods of the entities.. do you use those manytomany dependencies for comparisons?

Comment: Yes i know, that why i can't delete the EAGER... Don't know if i understand you well so i added the code of the methods i've wrote (forgot to wrote hashcode for Famille, don't know if it's a problem).